# how to find active/inactive status from specific date duration

Tags: sql-server-2008

Example : (CHECK Active and Inactive)

Duration - From Date: 2011-01-01
           To   Date: 2014-01-01

```
EMPID   ACTIVEDATE/REJOINING DATE       INACTIVEDATE

-----   ------------------------        -----------

1       NULL                           '2011-12-31'

2       '2012-01-01'                   '2011-12-31'

2       NULL                           '2013-12-31'

3       '2015-01-01'                   '2011-12-31'
```

I need below output:

```
Active
```

---

```
EMPID 
-----
```

### In Active

```
EMPID   
-----
```

1

2

3

Please send the exact SQL Query and also satisfied my condition.

Regards
Vino

Answer (score 0):

Just try this...

```
SELECT EmployeeID,CASE WHEN (ISNULL(MAX([REJOINING DATE]),'') > GETDATE()) OR (MAX(INACTIVEDATE) >ISNULL(MAX([REJOINING DATE]),'') ) THEN 'INACTIVE'
                       WHEN  (MAX(INACTIVEDATE) < ISNULL(MAX([REJOINING DATE]),'') ) AND (ISNULL(MAX([REJOINING DATE]),'') < GETDATE())  THEN 'ACTIVE'
                       ELSE  'N/A'
                 END AS 'Status'
 FROM @Table
```